# How to convert SDL_Surface to GtkImage

Tags: c, gtk, sdl

I'm doing a school project, and I already did a huge part on image processing with SDL, now I'm building a GUI with Glade and I need to convert my SDL_Surface to GtkImage to display every step of my processing on the GUI. How can I do it ?

I tried to convert my SDL_Surface to GdkPixbuf, that can easily be converted to GtkImage, but it didn't worked

```
struct _GdkPixbuf *convertToGdk(SDL_Surface *img)
{
  struct _GdkPixbuf *pb = gdk_pixbuf_new(GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB, FALSE, 8, img->w, img->h);
  pb->pixels = img->pixels;

  return pb;
}
```

Then I call the function

```
gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(user),convertToGdk(sdl_image));
```

It doesn't even compile, I got this error and I don't understand why

```
main.c: In function ‘convertToGdk’:
main.c:16:5: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct _GdkPixbuf’
   pb->pixels = img->pixels;
     ^~
```

I've included gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h of course

Comment: Before the GdkPixbuf typedef, the gdk-core.h file states **/* All of these are opaque structures */**.  So it doesn't look like they exposed the struct.  I'm not familiar with this library, but I'll upvote the question and maybe someone else can suggest an alternative to `gdk_pixbuf_new`.  Perhaps a function that takes the pixel data directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use raw pixel data directly unless it is in the correct format.

The code below takes care of converting the pixel data to the correct format. It works with any SDL surface:

```
GtkWidget * gtk_image_new_from_sdl_surface (SDL_Surface *surface)
{
    Uint32 src_format;
    Uint32 dst_format;

    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;
    gboolean has_alpha;
    int rowstride;
    guchar *pixels;

    GtkWidget *image;

    // select format                                                            
    src_format = surface->format->format;
    has_alpha = SDL_ISPIXELFORMAT_ALPHA(src_format);
    if (has_alpha) {
        dst_format = SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA32;
    }
    else {
        dst_format = SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB24;
    }

    // create pixbuf                                                            
    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new (GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB, has_alpha, 8,
                             surface->w, surface->h);
    rowstride = gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride (pixbuf);
    pixels = gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels (pixbuf);

    // copy pixels                                                              
    SDL_LockSurface(surface);
    SDL_ConvertPixels (surface->w, surface->h, src_format,
               surface->pixels, surface->pitch,
               dst_format, pixels, rowstride);
    SDL_UnlockSurface(surface);

    // create GtkImage from pixbuf                                              
    image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf (pixbuf);

    // release our reference to the pixbuf                                      
    g_object_unref (pixbuf);

    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data()](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-Image-Data-in-Memory.html#gdk-pixbuf-new-from-data) should work for 8 bit RGB -- you'll just have to find the details of the SDL pixel format to fill in the function arguments. Note that Pixbuf will not make a copy: it will keep using the pixel data you pass it (so make a copy yourself or make sure that the SDL_Surface won't free the data prematurely).

Comment: Or create 'empty' pixbuf and use `gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels` to fill it later.